# Azure CLI - Bash script to set up API Management custom domain

Tags: bash, azure-cli

I am trying to set up a custom domain in api management using a bash script.  I know it can be done using powershell

```
# Upload the custom ssl certificate to be applied to Proxy endpoint / Api Gateway endpoint
$proxyCertUploadResult = Import-AzApiManagementHostnameCertificate -Name $apimServiceName - 
ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -HostnameType "Proxy" -PfxPath $proxyCertificatePath - 
PfxPassword $proxyCertificatePassword

# Upload the custom ssl certificate to be applied to Portal endpoint
$portalCertUploadResult = Import-AzApiManagementHostnameCertificate -Name $apimServiceName - 
ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -HostnameType "Portal" -PfxPath $portalCertificatePath - 
PfxPassword $portalCertificatePassword

# Create the HostnameConfiguration object for Portal endpoint
$PortalHostnameConf = New-AzApiManagementHostnameConfiguration -Hostname $proxyHostname - 
CertificateThumbprint $proxyCertUploadResult.Thumbprint

# Create the HostnameConfiguration object for Proxy endpoint
$ProxyHostnameConf = New-AzApiManagementHostnameConfiguration -Hostname $portalHostname - 
CertificateThumbprint $portalCertUploadResult.Thumbprint

# Apply the configuration to API Management
Set-AzApiManagementHostnames -Name $apimServiceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -PortalHostnameConfiguration $PortalHostnameConf -ProxyHostnameConfiguration $ProxyHostnameConf
```

Is it possible to do a similar thing using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to configure custom domain for Azure API management with Azure CLI, we can use the command `az apim update --set hostnameConfigurations={setting}`.
The hostnameConfigurations setting should be like

```
[{
        "hostName": "bbb.beesphotos.net",
        "type": "Portal",
        "certificate": null,
        "certificatePassword": "<pfx file passsword>",
        "encodedCertificate": "Base64 Encoded certificate content"
    }, {
        "hostName": "huryapim.azure-api.net",
        "type": "Proxy",
        "certificate": null,
        "defaultSslBinding": true,
        "negotiateClientCertificate": false
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: I might not have the syntax right but when I run   az apim update --name myapim --resource-group MyRG --set hostnameConfigurations={[{"hostName": "bbb.hostname.com.au", "type": "Proxy", "keyVaultId": "https://mykeyvault/secrets/mysecret", "defaultSslBinding": true,"negotiateClientCertificate": true}]} I get the following error - Couldn't find 'bbb' in 'bbb.hostname'.

Comment: Please try to convert the json to string via https://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring. Then run again.

Comment: use "DeveloperPortal"  Legacy portal is deprecated

[{
        "hostName": "bbb.beesphotos.net",
        "type": "DeveloperPortal",
        "certificate": null,
        "certificatePassword": "<pfx file passsword>",
        "encodedCertificate": "Base64 Encoded certificate content"
    }, {
        "hostName": "huryapim.azure-api.net",
        "type": "Proxy",
        "certificate": null,
        "defaultSslBinding": true,
        "negotiateClientCertificate": false
    }
]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
        az apim update --resource-group $rgName --name $apiMgmtName `
        --add hostnameConfigurations type=Proxy host_name=$hostName `
        encodedCertificate=$certData certificatePassword=$certPassword `
        negotiateClientCertificate=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If some one is looking for complete script here it is.  Just change the parameter as per your need.  If you are using wildcard certificate then the keyvault id will be same for both gateway and for the developer portal.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [String]
    $ResourceGroupName,
    [String]
    $GatewayHostname,
    [String]
    $ApimServiceName,
    [String]
    $GatewayCertificateKeyVaultId,
    [String]
    $PortalHostname,
    [String]
    $PortalCertificateKeyVaultId
)
$config ='[{\"hostName\":\"'+$GatewayHostname+'\",\"type\":\"Proxy\",\"keyVaultId\":\"'+$GatewayCertificateKeyVaultId+'\",\"defaultSslBinding\":true,\"negotiateClientCertificate\":false},{\"hostName\":\"'+$PortalHostname+'\",\"type\":\"DeveloperPortal\",\"keyVaultId\":\"'+$PortalCertificateKeyVaultId+'\"}]'
Write-Host $config
az apim update --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --name  $ApimServiceName --set hostnameConfigurations=$config
```