# How to update the existing custom domain in APIM using Azure cli or PowerShell command

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-cli, apim

I am trying to update the existing APIM custom domain with new ssl certificate which is in keyvault. But couldn't find the command for the same. Can any one help me with cli or PowerShell command to achieve this.

Comment: we can use cli command to achieve this check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783017/failed-to-setup-custom-domain-for-apim-using-powershell-script

Comment: Hi @KSP if you solve your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.